# Using display inline-block columns move down

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use `display:inline-block` to build 3 columns.

It works fine in the beginning, but when I add content to the first column it affects the rest of the layout and renders the rest of the columns at a lower level.

What can I do to avoid this?

```css
.cont {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #666666;
}
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="col">
    test<br><br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    col2
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    col3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't see to illustrate your problem.

Comment: One thing to remember  with `inline-block` is to set a `margin-right: -4px`. This alleviates any issues with white-spacing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should add [`vertical-align: top;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) CSS declaration to align the columns vertically at the top:

```css
.cont span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;     /* Vertically align the inline-block elements */
    height:100%;
    line-height: 100%;
    width: 33.33%;           /* Just for Demo */
    outline: 1px dashed red; /* Just for Demo */
}
```

Here is a **[online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ge6g7/5/)**.

---

Honestly, I'm not a fan of using `inline-block` to create columns on the page, because of the [white spaces between them](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

The [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) was being used for a while, but nowadays [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) box or CSS [`grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) can be an option.

Comment: `inline-block` is wonderful because it remains in the doc flow and alleviates the need for clear-fixing.

Comment: @AdamSimpson Any suggestions are welcome, what I said was my opinion comes from over 12 years of web developing experience.

Comment: @aSeptik I read OP questions twice, he didn't mention that the content should be in the middle, the point is because the columns are rendered in document normal flow, they affect each other.

Comment: @HashemQolami Still Useful in 2018 :) Awesome

Answer (score -1):

You just have to set a width of 33% on the the column, this will constraint it to take up 33% of the entire width of the div.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ge6g7/1/

```
.cont {
    height:60px;
    background: #ffff88;
}
.cont span {
    display: inline-block;
    height:100%;
    line-height: 100%;
    width: 33%; /* Added Css */
}
```

Comment: @aSeptik - The OP did not say anything about putting the content in the middle, unless I misread something.