# div hover effect changed after adding text-content

Tags: html, css, hover, border

The moment I added text in my div, the hover effect changed. The hover effect was to increase the border width but it started moving the other divs in the same line. If I remove text from just **ONE** div of all the divs appearing in one line, the hover effect is okay. But it persists on the next line.

The fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/u716vyoL/1/

Here is my code:
CSS

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .ProcOuterDiv{
        #margin:4px 5px 4px 5px;
        display:inline-block;
        height:26px;
        width:26px;
    }
    .Proc{
        margin:2px 2px 2px 2px;
        height:23px;
        width:23px;
        #padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;
        border: 2px solid #A3A0FA;
        border-radius: 1px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .Proc:hover{
        border: 3px solid #F77C60;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor:pointer;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0px 0px 8px rgba(252, 69, 69, 0.8) !important;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="1" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">Cr</div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="2" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">Br</div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="3" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">Ca</div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="4" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">Fill</div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="5" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc"></div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="6" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">Im</div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="7" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">RC</div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="8" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">Den</div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="9" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">MOB</div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="10" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">Im</div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="11" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">SP</div></div>
```

Comment: This is a [well-known](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154707/using-display-inline-block-columns-move-down) [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward) with `inline-block`s, You could [align them](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/u716vyoL/3/) at the top of the container by `vertical-align: top;` declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In your code default border width for div.Proc is 2px and OnHover of increase border width by 1px, so element have jerk in border and spacing between two elements.
- In your code you apply shadow only on hove but i give default shadow and color is transparent and on hover color will be change. so looking nice!

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/au11o4wr/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="1" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">Cr</div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="2" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">Br</div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="3" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">Ca</div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="4" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">Fill</div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="5" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc"></div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="6" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">Im</div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="7" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">RC</div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="8" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">Den</div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="9" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">MOB</div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="10" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">Im</div></div><!--
--><div class="ProcOuterDiv"><div data-val1="11" onclick="SelectProc(this);" class="Proc">SP</div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
.ProcOuterDiv{
    #margin:4px 5px 4px 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    height:26px;
    width:26px;
}
.Proc{
    margin:2px 2px 2px 2px;
    height:23px;
    width:23px;
    #padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;
    border: 3px solid #A3A0FA;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px transparent inset, 0px 0px 8px transparent;
    border-radius: 1px;
    text-align:center;
}
.Proc:hover{
    border: 3px solid #F77C60;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0px 0px 8px rgba(252, 69, 69, 0.8);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. About your comment for the border, I have an outer div which is 26px , I used it to provide cushion to the inner div  which is 23px. So I was expecting that outer div will absorb the jerk created by one additional pixel by the inner div but that didn't work, conceptually it should have. Anyways, I appreciate you taking time and providing me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/u716vyoL/2/) what you want!

I just removed 'border-radius' property and replaced 'border' property with 'outline' property.

```
outline: 2px solid #A3A0FA;
```

Comment: Thanks @Leo, the outline actually creates additional border around the existing BLUE border, which was not exactly what I planned. Anyway, thanks for your support.