# CSS Columns Don't Fill Parent Container As Expected

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I have a layout using the CSS columns, and I would like it so the child items fill the respective column-count value.

In the code below I have 3 columns via the `column-count: 3;` property, but the layout never goes wider than 2 columns unless I remove the `display: inline-block;` on the child items (`.column`).

However if I remove this 'display: inline-block', it gives me three columns, but it breaks the columns themselves.

The same problem occurs if you comment out the 3rd column in the HTML, then you only have the 2 columns effectively stacking on top of each other instead of filling the width of the parent container?

Is there anyway to have it so the shows the correct number of columns, and as the window sizes reduces they always fill the entire width of the parent section element?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/thechewy/pen/xxdQyYE

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

section {
  background: red;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 2rem;
  column-width: 300px; /* sets the equivalent of min-width when combined with column count */
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.column-2 {
  background: yellow;
}

.column-3 {
  background: blue;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="column column-1">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio obcaecati, consectetur quos sed similique ipsum? Obcaecati modi totam, dolorem ratione optio distinctio omnis harum deserunt dignissimos consequatur, in eveniet sequi.</p>
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1rErAWAR319I1tfi_vMHKYgcvBY7vrfQp">
  </div>
  <div class="column column-2">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio obcaecati, consectetur quos sed similique ipsum? Obcaecati modi totam, dolorem ratione optio distinctio omnis harum deserunt dignissimos consequatur, in eveniet sequi.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column column-3">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Have you adjusted the box-sizing property?

Comment: @Paulie_D - actually adding `* {box-sizing: border-box; position: relative}` makes the column gap property work. Thanks for that idea. Now I just need to work out the main problem. I'll remove that bit from the question.

Comment: Use a standard div instead of section, set the column-count on this div, and don't use individual divs for each column.

Comment: See also https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

Comment: @Atrix there's no point me trying that because a) there's no reason columns won't work on a `section` and b) if I remove the divs for each column the browser won't know that those wrappers are what are supposed to be the columns. It'll just do the math/layout on everything.

Comment: Try adding a vertical-align: top;  to the .column css, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154707/using-display-inline-block-columns-move-down

Comment: @Atrix it's not a vertical alignment issue.

Comment: Some tips for others: First, try avoiding setting `inline-block`. Second, if you're using `column-count` like OP, it's highly likely you'd also end up using `column-fill` and on children `break-before`, `break-after`, `break-inside` to get the desired behaviour. Third, before exploring anything, set a hard pixel height number (e.g. `height:800px`) on the parent wrapping the element that has `column-count`, then deal with it later. For whatever reason, my parent height was not always respected until I set a hard pixel height.

Answer (score -2):

Try setting the column-gap in pixels.

Comment: You should copy the snippet to your answer and make changes to demonstrate your solution.

Comment: That's not the issue. I've tweaked the question with regards to the column-gap property.